# How to extract polygons that are not in one layer and overlap maybe a little bit

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have two layers.  Some polygons overlap and some have new polygons that are not in my main layer however they overlap at some intersections. How can i select and extract only the polygons that are not in my main layer and have this data as a shape file or feature class.IE get only the polygons that are on my second layer which has additions to the main layer basically.
[image]

Comment: A screenshot would sure help me understand!

Comment: I added a screenshot @Stu Smith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, let's call your two polygon layers **Green** and **Blue**.  If I understand correctly, you want to:

- Select those **Blue** polygons that DO NOT intersect any **Green** polygons.
- Export the selected **Blue** polygons to a third layer

To select the **Blue** polygons, I would first use the *Selection > Select By Location* tool, with **Blue** as the Target layer, **Green** as the Source layer, and *intersect the source layer feature* as the Spatial selection method.  The intersecting **Blue** polygons are now highlighted.  Next, right-click the Blue layer in the Table of Contents and drop down to *Selection > Switch Selection*.  This has the effect of selecting those Blue polygons that DO NOT intersect Green polygons, which is what you want.

In the Table of Contents, right-click the **Blue** layer and drop down to *Data > Export Data*. Enter the output path and name.  Voila! - the third layer, containing only the intersecting **Blue** polygons, is created.

Comment: Hi,

This would get me the polygons that intersect however I don't want that all I want are only the new ones that are in one layer which do not exist in the other.

Comment: Please clarify... what do you mean by "...do not exist in the other."?

Comment: I mean that blue polygon is not in the base layer.

Comment: Do you want just those blue polygons that do not intersect any green polygons?

Comment: Yes. I want the blue polygons like the arrow is point to at the top diagram

Comment: I have edited my answer, based on your information.